# How to correct config Apache and Codeigniter?

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

I am using Apache + Codeigniter to setup an RESTful backend service.

I placed codeigniter's project folder html/ under my Apache's web folder.
Then I can access it by http://localhost/html/index.php.
I want to remove the folder name in my url, access my web like that http://localhost/index.php.

Could anyone can tell me how to config on Apache side or Codeigniter?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

In Apache folder, just open filename `httpd.conf` and put this code at the bottom:

```
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot "D:/htdocs/html/"
</VirtualHost>
```

Tell me, if it works.

Comment: I tried, that's works. But found another problem, all images of my web cannot show up. Seems the image's location not works well. Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: My fault, the image not show up caused the $config['base_url'] of Codeigniter still have html/ path. All works after remove html/ from my $config['base_url'].